# How to create empty txt files in a directory reflecting files in another directory?

Tags: linux, rename

I need to do some testing and need the same file names as I have in directory /home/recordings in /home/testing folder.

For example, if i have a file recording01.mp4 in /home/recordings,  i would want to have the an empty file recording01.txt or recording01.mp4 or in /home/testing

I understand I can use the following command?

```
for i in /home/recordings/*; do touch "$i"; done
```

Not sure how to specify extension or the destination directory in this case?

Comment: The command looks good and should be appropriate for your requirement.

Comment: but how do i change destination if i needed all files in /home/testing/* ?

Comment: Given answer check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this without a loop

```
find /home/recordings/ -type f -printf /home/testing/%f'\n' | xargs -n1 touch
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple addition of `/home/testing/` to touch command will do it.

```
    for i in /home/recordings/*; do 
          temp=`echo $i|cut -f3 -d'/'`
          cd /home/testing/
          touch "$temp"; 
          cd ../..
    done
```

I assume you are not in `home` directory and running this script file from anywhere else.

Comment: touch: cannot touch ‘/home/testing//home/recordings/rec001.mp4’: No such file or directory. It looks like it stored a path instead of a file name into a variable

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i in /home/recordings/*; do touch "/home/testing/$i"; done
```

You need only specify absolute paths and things will work fine. A bunch of 0-length files are created, their names corresponding to those in `/home/recordings`.